# How to pick color from buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have html tables,and I would like to change its colors by picking up from button and clicking cells.

First,I would like to select colors from buttons,

↓

Second,When I select colors from buttons,I would like to click cells to change color.

↓

Third,After selecting colors,Can I change cell's color by clicking on it?

```
<tr>
<td>color</td>
</tr>

<button>yellow</button>
<button>aqua</button>
```

At first I assume it will realize by changing td's class,but I couldn't find out the ways.

If someone has experienced such method,please let me know.

Thanks

```
td {
  background-color: yellow;
  }

td {
  background-color: aqua;
  }
```

Comment: Put the color styling in their own CSS classes, then add/remove those classes from the `td` elements when the relevant button is clicked

Comment: You could also have elements in both colors present and toggle the visibility of each by an on click event.

Comment: If your table has 10 TDs, by clicking the button, you want all the TDs to change background color?

Comment: Can you please put your code in jsfiddle

Comment: @Harshsetia Please do not ask for code representations on external sites. Stackoverflow has very good snippet functionality.

Comment: What have you attempted? Which part of that attempt is causing you difficulty?  It would be easy enough for someone to write your solution for you (and someone probably will for rep) but it would be better for you to be guided and to guide we need to know what's causing you difficulty.   eg "changing TD's class" is `$("td").click(() => $(this).toggleClass("yellow"))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this once. It's working

```js
var color = 'black';

$('.click_btn').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  color = $(this).css('color');
})

$('.click_td').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).css('color', color);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="click_td">color</td>
    <td class="click_td">color II</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<button class="click_btn" style="color:yellow;">yellow</button>
<button class="click_btn" style="color:aqua;">aqua</button>
```

Comment: Can you convert this to an SO snippet so that we can see it working?

Comment: I've converted it. Check it now @freedomn-m

Comment: Updated to a snippet

Answer (score 2):

Use this code-

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#color1").click(function(){
    $(".table td").css("background","red");
  });
  $("#color2").click(function(){
    $(".table td").css("background","aqua");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>My First Web Page</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>My Table</h1>
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>Airport Code</th>
        <th>Common Name/City</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>CWA</td>
        <td>Central Wisconsin Airport</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>ORD</td>
        <td>Chicago O'Hare</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>LHR</td>
        <td>London Heathrow</td>
    </tr>
</table>

<button id="color1">Select Red</button>
<button id="color2">Select aqua</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Although OPs description isn't the clearest, this doesn't follow the process "click button to select colour, then click cell to set that cell to the previously selected colour"